# How to compare classes in order of least to highest?

Tags: python, list, class

How do i compare different employees on bases of pay in the following code:

```
import random

class employee:
  def __init__(self, pay, age):
    self.pay = pay
    self.age = age


employee_num = 0 
for i in range(5):
  
  employee_num = employee(random.randint(20000, 50000),random.randint(18, 59))
  #create different employee numbers and make the pay and age of these employee_num random
  


# compairing different employee numbers on base of pay in order from least to most
print('printing highest earner employee number here')


#delete all employee classes here
```

or can I make a list with this data to access it easier?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: To start, you need an actual list of employees, rather than just overwriting each previous employee with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random


class Employee: # Convention capitalize class names
    def __init__(self, pay, age):
        self.pay = pay
        self.age = age


employees = []
for i in range(5):
    employees.append( Employee(random.randint(20000, 50000),
                            random.randint(18, 59)))
    # create different employee numbers and make the pay and age of these
    # employee_num random

# compairing different employee numbers on base of pay in order from least to most
print('printing highest earner employee number here')
for person in employees:
    print(person.pay)

print('Now process from least to most pay.')
# Mutate the employees list ordered by lowest of highest pay.
employees.sort(key=lambda employee: employee.pay)
for person in employees:
    print(person.pay)
    
# delete all employee classes here
```

Output

```
printing highest earner employee number here
28717
48714
25406
33588
23827
Now process from least to most pay.
23827
25406
28717
33588
48714
```

Comment: If you are not familiar with lambda functions, the key can be done using a function. Post a comment if any clarification is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning the `employee_num` 5 times. what does it mean?
to sort a list with your order you can do this:

```py
employee_list = [employee(random.randint(20000, 50000), random.randint(18, 59)) for i in range(5)]
employee_list.sort(key=lambda e: e.pay) #this will sort the list with the employee.pay ascending
```

or you can override the relation operators for your class and use them:

```py
class employee:
  def __init__(self, pay, age):
    self.pay = pay
    self.age = age
  def __gt__(self, a):
    return self.pay > a.pay
  def __lt__(self, a):
    return self.pay < a.pay

...

employee_list.sort()
```

Comment: I wanted to make employee_numb variables but I made it wrong…..